# HTML 5 embed into SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, html

Is there a reason SharePoint restricts some HTML 5 commands when embedded?

For example, when I embed this

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

SharePoint changes it to

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="" unselectable="on">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" unselectable="on">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" unselectable="on">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Making it where I have to right click to play the video. Also, the "autoplay" function works while I am editing the embedded code, but as soon as I save the work, it takes autoplay out of my code.

I am hoping someone can point out a feature I have disabled to fix this. Thank you for any assistance you can give.

Comment: are you embedding it in a Content Editor WebPart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also observed this behavior while adding an HTML5 video to content editor webpart a month back. I don't know the reason as to why this is happening. But I found a workaround. Try changing your code to:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Notice the use of `controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"`

See this for more information: [SharePoint 2013: HTML5 video](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/06/SharePoint-HTML-5-Video.html)